# Azure queue binding to Azure function to process message synchronously

Tags: azure, design-patterns, azure-functions, message-queue, synchronous

What is the ideal method to design a synchronous queue for an Azure function to prevent parallel processing? The function would execute the next queue request after the current one is finished.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: Look at this article.  https://laurakokkarinen.com/forcing-an-azure-function-to-process-queue-storage-messages-one-at-a-time/